# How to supply password from shell script without using expect command

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

I'm writing a bash script to stop start my postgres DB service. Initially I succeeded in creating one, but as soon I enabled SSL certificate it prompts to enter the phrase password.

I know the easiest solution is to use expect , but in my environment i am not authorized to use it.

Can someone help me out in scripting as to how can I supply the PEM PHRASE password without a user intervention.

This is what I have worked so far.

```
-bash-4.2$ cat start_postgres_db.sh

cd `dirname $0`

. `dirname $0`/parameter.env

${POSTGREBIN}/pg_ctl -D ${POSTGREDATAPATH} start -w

while true

do

sleep 1

loopcnt=0

loopcnt=`expr ${loopcnt} + 1`

PRCCNT=`ps -ef | grep ${DBEXENAME} | grep -v grep|wc -l`

if [ ${PRCCNT} -eq 1 ]

then

        echo "PostgreSQL process started sucessfully"

        exit
fi

if [ ${loopcnt} -gt 11 ]

then

    echo "PostgreSQL process not started successfully"

    echo "su to postgres and run ${POSTGREBIN}/pg_ctl -D ${POSTGREDATAPATH} restart"

    exit
fi

done
```

Execution:

```
bash-4.2$ ./start_postgres_db.sh

waiting for server to start....Enter PEM pass phrase:.........
```

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a password to `pg_ctl` as argument on the command line with the option `-P`. I will assume it is contained in the variable `${POSTGREPASSWORD}`.

**start_postgres_db.sh**

```sh
cd `dirname $0`
. `dirname $0`/parameter.env

${POSTGREBIN}/pg_ctl start -w -D ${POSTGREDATAPATH} -P ${POSTGREPASSWORD}

while true; do

  sleep 1
  (( loopcnt++ ))

  PRCCNT=$(ps -ef | grep ${DBEXENAME} | grep -v grep | wc -l)

  if [ ${PRCCNT} -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "PostgreSQL process started sucessfully"
    exit 0
  fi

  if [ ${loopcnt} -gt 11 ]; then
    echo "PostgreSQL process not started successfully"
    echo "su to postgres and run ${POSTGREBIN}/pg_ctl -D ${POSTGREDATAPATH} restart"
    exit 1
  fi

done
```

Comment: Already tried that. according to postgres document.  pg_ctl -P  option is available in windows for user to start the service. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: I understand: this seems to be valid only for Windows and with the command `pg_ctl register`. They mention something about the `-w` option at https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAA-aLv4TLRP_xemnsV18kaLBE3tH7BbA-WBxm6CPv_p%2B%2BzKSrA%40mail.gmail.com